# Why does a match on covariant enum does not behave the same as with a sealed trait?

Tags: scala, scala-3

Why does this produce an error?

```scala
import scala.io.StdIn

enum Flow[+A] {
  case Say (text: String) extends Flow[Unit]
  case Ask extends Flow[String]
}

def eval [T](flow: Flow[T]): T = flow match {
  case Flow.Say(text) => println(text)
  case Flow.Ask => StdIn.readLine // error here
}
```

```
18 |  case Flow.Ask => StdIn.readLine
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                   Found:    String
   |                   Required: T
```

(no error if the enum is left invariant on T)

But when the enum is replaced with a (seemingly equivalent?) ADT implemented with a sealed trait, no such error is reported:

```scala
sealed trait Flow[+A]
object Flow {
  case class Say(text: String) extends Flow[Unit]
  case object Ask extends Flow[String]
}
// match statement in eval works fine
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can look at [the initial proposal](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1970) which added enums to Scala 3 for some insight.

By the wording of this proposal, enum cases fall into three categories.

> - Class cases are those cases that are parameterized, either with a type parameter section [...] or with one or more (possibly empty) parameter sections (...).
> - Simple cases are cases of a non-generic enum class that have neither parameters nor an extends clause or body. That is, they consist of a name only.
> - Value cases are all cases that do not have a parameter section but that do have a (possibly generated) extends clause and/or a body.

Let's take a look at your `enum` declaration.

```
enum Flow[+A] {
  case Say (text: String) extends Flow[Unit]
  case Ask extends Flow[String]
}
```

Now, simple cases are right out, because your enum is generic. Your `Say` is pretty clearly a class case, since it's parameterized. `Ask`, on the other hand, is non-generic and non-enumerated, so it's a value case. If we scroll down a bit, we see what value cases do

> (6) A value case
>
> ```
> case C extends <parents> <body>
> ```
>
> expands to a value definition
>
> ```
> val C = new <parents> { <body>; def enumTag = n; $values.register(this) }
> ```
>
> where `n` is the ordinal number of the case in the companion object, starting from 0. The statement `$values.register(this)` registers the value as one of the `enumValues` of the enumeration (see below). `$values` is a compiler-defined private value in the companion object.

The bottom line here is that `Ask` is not defined as

```
object Ask extends Flow[String]
```

but more like

```
val Ask = new Flow[String]() { ... }
```

So your pattern match

```
case Flow.Ask => StdIn.readLine
```

is actually an *equality check* against the *value* `Flow.Ask`, rather than a type check against a singleton object. The former, unfortunately, proves nothing to the compiler about the generic type of your value, so it remains `T`, as opposed to specializing to `String`.

The rationale for this is provided on the same page

> ## Objectives
>
> ...
>
> 2. Enumerations should be efficient, even if they define many values. In particular, we should avoid defining a new class for every value.
>
> ...

So it seems the Scala developers wanted to avoid the bloat that would result from an enum declaring tons of unparameterized values (i.e. a type that looks like an ordinary Java-style enum).

The simple solution, then, is to provide a parameter list

```
case Ask() extends Flow[String]
```

It's ever so slightly more cumbersome to work with, but it does define a new type, and then your pattern match

```
case Flow.Ask() => StdIn.readLine
```

will succeed